# Uno de mis contenedores principales se visualiza "aplastado " como si su width de 0. ¿Qué esta ocurriendo? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Nada debería estar por fuera del body (linea azul) el cual esta seteado al tamaño del viewport. Nótese que todos los elementos por debajo el cronometro se encuentran aplastados contra el margen izquierdo.

**Contexto**: estoy haciendo un cronometro el cual tiene una ventana contraíble donde se guardan los tiempo pero al comenzar el proceso de pasarlo a responsive surgió un problema con la misma.

**Intención**: la idea es que el resto del contenido de la pagina ocupe un lugar fijo (es decir no adapte su tamaño dinámicamente) y que justo debajo se visualiza lo que era la ventana solo que esta vez como parte del layout.

**Problema**: Por algún motivo que no logro determinar el contenido de la ventana queda "aplastado" en su ancho (como si tuviera un `width` de `0`) además, tampoco logro encontrar el motivo por el cual si al contenedor principal de la ex-ventana le di un `height` de `calc(100%-Tamaño_del_resto_de_los_elementos_en_pixeles)` el contenido colapsa tanto del `body`.

```css
:root {
  --color-a: rgb(255, 238, 0);
  --color-b: black;
}


/* RESET BASICO */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* TAGS */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: url(../images/fondo1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* border: solid blue; */
  height: 100vh;
}

.cronos {
  padding: .5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: var(--color-a);
  font-weight: lighter;
}


/* CLASES */

.js {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 12px 2px 3px 12px;
  background-color: var(--color-a)
}

.version {
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42.5%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: var(--color-b);
  opacity: .9;
}

.tiempos {
  border: solid red;
  height: 100%;
  /* width: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* justify-content:center; */
}

.controles {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn--ctrl {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: var(--color-a);
  color: var(--color-b);
  height: 25%;
}

.no--implementado {
  /* Elementos en desarrollo */
  opacity: .3;
}

.cronometro {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contChild {
  text-align: end;
  /* min-width: 260px; */
  /* border: solid 14px; */
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.contador {
  font-size: 200px;
  color: var(--color-a);
}

.separador {
  font-size: 200px;
  color: var(--color-a);
}

.atribucion {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--color-a);
  font-style: italic;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: var(--color-b);
  padding: 10px;
}

.atribucion a {
  background-color: var(--color-a);
  color: var(--color-b);
  padding: 1px 10px;
}

.ventana--tiempos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: var(--color-b);
  border-left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 1;
  /* solo para ver el colapso */
}

.tiempos--header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* text-align: left; */
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: var(--color-a);
  color: var(--color-b);
}

.btn--ocultarV {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 21%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.btn--ocultarV img {
  width: 25px;
}

.titulo--registro {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 75%;
}

.titulo--registro_moviles {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color-a);
}

.btn--resetList {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: var(--color-a);
  color: var(--color-b);
}

.contenedor--registros {
  border: solid black 1px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.registro {
  cursor: no-drop;
  border-bottom: var(--color-a) solid 1px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.registro--fecha {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: var(--color-a);
}

.registro--tiempo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--color-a);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .contenedor--logo {
    border: solid green 1px;
    height: 40px;
  }
  body {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 100vh;
    border: solid blue 1px;
  }
  .container {
    border: solid red 1px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .cronometro {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .controles {
    width: 100%;
    /* border: solid red; */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .btn--ctrl {
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: var(--color-a);
    color: var(--color-b);
  }
  .tiempos {
    display: none;
  }
  /* .contador, .separador{
            font-size: 20vw;
        } */
  .ventana--tiempos {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: static;
    max-width: 100vh;
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
    max-height: calc(100%-340px);
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .tiempos--header {
    display: none;
  }
  .contenedor--registros {
    border: solid black 1px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    flex-grow: none;
  }
  .titulo--registro_moviles {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--color-a);
  }
  .registro {
    cursor: no-drop;
    border-bottom: var(--color-a) solid 1px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 5px 0;
  }
  .atribucion {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CRONOS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contenedor--logo">
    <h1><span class="js">JS</span><span class="cronos">CRONOS</span><span class="version">v0.1.3</span></h1>
  </div>

  <!-- <div class="contenedor--principal"> -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="controles">
      <button id="btnIniciar" class="btn--ctrl">Iniciar</button>
      <button id="btnDetener" class="btn--ctrl">Detener</button>
      <button id="btnReset" class="btn--ctrl">Resetear</button>
      <button id="btnGuardar" class="btn--ctrl">Guardar</button>
    </div>

    <div class="cronometro">
      <div class="contChild"><span class="contador" id="min">00</span></div>
      <div><span class="separador"> : </span></div>
      <div class="contChild"><span class="contador" id="seg">00</span></div>
      <div><span class="separador"> . </span></div>
      <div class="contChild"><span class="contador" id="miSeg">00</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="tiempos">
      <button id="btnTiempos" class="btn--ctrl">Tiempos</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="atribucion">Foto de <a href="https://unsplash.com/@bradencollum?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Braden Collum</a> en <a href="https://unsplash.com/es/fotos/9HI8UJMSdZA?utm_source=unsplash&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=creditCopyText">Unsplash</a></p>
  <div class="ventana--tiempos" id="ventanaTiempos">
    <div id="btnOcultarVtn" class="tiempos--header">
      <div class="btn--ocultarV">
        <img src="images/flecha.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="titulo--registro">
        <p>TIEMPOS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="titulo--registro_moviles">
      <p>TIEMPOS</p>
    </div>
    <div id="registros" class="contenedor--registros"></div>
    <!-- Los registros se generaran dinamicamente con js -->
    <button id="btnRresetList" class="btn--resetList">Borrar registro</button>
  </div>
  <!-- </div> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola Matias, a mi no me queda claro cual es el problema o como reproducirlo.

Comment: Buen día, ¿podrías especificar cuál es el problema o adjuntar una imagen del resultado esperado?

Comment: Hola Marcos y Cris223511.dev, acabo de agregar mas información sobre el problema y una imagen de como se ve las pagina ahora, tengan en cuanta que el problema se genera por debajo de 1024px.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno es que de hecho tienes un `width: 0` en `.ventana--tiempos` asumo que en desktop lo quieres así y en móvil no, no es muy clara la explicación, pero en tu `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)` también pon el width que quieres si no va a heredar el `width: 0`

Y al `height: calc(100%-Tamaño_del_resto_de_los_elementos_en_pixeles)`, que en realidad creo que te refieres al `max-height` en `.ventana--tiempos`, solo ponle espacio entre el operador "-" así:

```
height: calc(100% - 340px)
```